# MomentJS defaulting to Eastern Time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to default the date to New York timezone.
Here is what the problem is: If I use the following method in two different machines, one in Eastern and one in Central time, I get two different timezone information:

```
moment.utc(date)
```

For Eastern: `2018-12-15T05:00:00.000Z`
For Central: `2018-12-15T06:00:00.000Z`
I want something from moment JS in the above method so that machine in central timezone also gives me:
 `2018-12-15T05:00:00.000Z`
This is something related to defaulting the timezone to Eastern but I am not sure how to do it.
P.S.: The method should consider daylight saving changes as well.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting different results on machines in different timezones?  `moment.utc` should return dates in UTC, aka GMT, not local time -- that's what the "[Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))" in the format represents.  You can convert from there to the user's local time.

Comment: (And you *definitely* want to default to UTC if you're doing any kind of cross-time-zone calculations, don't default to Eastern; storing your data in any local zone becomes a nightmare when daylight savings changes happen.)

Comment: @DanielBeck - Yes these dates are UTC. That is why I get 5:00:00 for Eastern and 6:00:00 for Central. My requirement is that even if I get the UTC time from Central, I want to convert to Eastern. And yes, good point about Daylight saving changes. I will add that to the question. Thanks!

Comment: If you run `moment.utc()` in two different timezones at the same time you should be getting the same exact result from both.  UTC is its own zone, the local time doesn't come into play at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly painlessly using `Moment timezone`. Please take a look at the excerpt below via their docs:

> By default, moment objects are created in the local time zone.
>   Local time zone - it's a time zone which is set in a browser or on your node.js >server.
>
> To change the default time zone, use moment.tz.setDefault with a valid time zone.
>
> moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");

In your case, you will want to pass in your date like so:

```
var a = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/New_York");
```

for more information take a look here: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment-timezone/01-using-timezones/00-intro/